# Git Server Config (--bare structure / isage)

Tags: git, server, repo

I am still struggling a little with the logic and the proper use / purpose of the --bare repo on a local git server.

On the server I can create the bare repo (repo.git) easily. I understand this bare repo is required. What I do not quite understand is the role / file struture.

Is the bare repo.git and umbrella for all of my future repos or do I need a new bare repo for every project I want to be a repo on my server. for example:

repo.git
-project1-repo
-project2-repo
-project3-repo

Or will I need this setup:
repo1.git
-project1-repo
repo2.git
-project2-repo
repo3.git
-project3-repo

So really what I want to achieve is a repo server which I can manage various websites/apps individually. I was using GitHub with one repo and multiple directories which contain each site/app within. Sadly some of my projects have grown too big for Git Hub.

I hope this makes sense. Any clarification is helpful.

Comment: take one of your regular, non-bare clone, and inspect the content of the `.git/` directory at its root. This is `git`'s database, the place where it stores all its information on your local clone. A bare repository is "just the `.git/` directory". The structure of that directory is managed by git.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "too big for GitHub" ?

Comment: Yes, 50MB limit

Comment: Yes, I understand now that the bare git is the "database". So just to confirm, will I need a bare repo on the server for each local (working) repo? Of can I put several local repos under this one "master bare" in a sense like an umbrella for all local reops? Thank you LeGEC,

Comment: "50MB limit" on a single file ? use `git lfs`  <- a tool to still keep track of your big files in your repo, but store their content in a content server next to it

Comment: Thank you for that tip. At this point, I much prefer to use my own local server anyway.

Comment: So I think it is fair to assume that I need 1 x bare repo for each working repo. I will try this tonight after work.

Comment: Perhaps you can answer and I will select your reply as the best answer